# How can I convert the following bash script to something that will run flawlessly on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell

```
for i in `cut -d, -f 2 some_file.csv | uniq | tr -d "\""`; do grep -w $i some_file.csv > some_file_$i.csv; done
```

Basically I run this on my Linux workstation right now but I need to pass this to a non-technical guy using a Windows workstation. Even I'm not a Windows admin so no idea how to run it in Windows 'script'. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't just convert it to "Windows Script"(batch). Because Windows Script/Batch has a completely different syntax.

Comment: You can probably ask that user to install cygwin/msys and so on.

Comment: This looks like CSV parsing, which Powershell supports pretty well. What, exactly, is the script supposed to do?

Comment: Look for those command equivalences from bash to batch/powershell

Comment: Ask your user to install [windows subsystem for linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

Comment: This script extracts $value from the second field of a CSV file, sorts and removes duplicates, then removes the quotation marks from that $value and then again sorts the entire CSV file against that $value and finally creates separate CSV files as per that $value.

Comment: Allow me to illustrate via an example.
For e.g., lets say I need to parse a single CSV file containing all pet animals/birds and their attributes. All I need to do is, extract the name of the animals from the 2nd field, remove duplicates > remove "" marks and then create separate CSVs containing the attributes of a particular pet animal, e.g. from some.csv I need to create some_dogs.csv, some_cats.csv and so on. Sorry if this sounds silly.

Comment: Rewrite the logic in PowerShell.

Comment: I've seldom used Windows in my life, let alone Powershell :(

Comment: I think you'll need to give it a try first, rather than asking others to just do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell supports CSV parsing just fine, try the `Import-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv some_file.csv -Header 1,2 |Select-Object -ExpandProperty 2 |Sort-Object -Unique
```

`Import-Csv` will parse the file, and emit an object (per line) with two properties: `1` and `2`, corresponding to the first and second column in the file.

The `Select-Object` statement will grab the values from the `2` property and throw away the rest.

`Sort-Object -Unique` will sort the column values and remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you'd split the CSV by grouping the records by the identifying field and exporting each group separately:

```
$csv   = 'C:\path\to\some.csv'
$field = 'fieldname'

Import-Csv $csv | Group-Object $field | ForEach-Object {
  $name = $_.Name
  $_.Group | Export-Csv "C:\path\to\output_$name.csv" -NoType
}
```

Note that you need to know the name of the field for this. If you want to split by the second field regardless of its name (which I don't recommend) you need to determine the name of that field first. I'm going to leave that as an exercise for the reader.